# Scala foldLeft too many parameters

Tags: scala, parameters, foldleft

I have a list of tuples called `item`, each index in the list contains 2 x `Double`s e.g.

```
item = ((1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (10.0, 100.0))
```

I want to perform a calculation on each index within the list `item` and I'm trying to do it with `foldLeft`. This is my code:

```
item.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + myMethod(_._2, _._1, item.size)))
```

`_._2` accesses the current `item` Tuple at index 1 and `_._1` accesses the current `item` Tuple at index 0. e.g. for the first fold it should effectively be:

```
item.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + myMethod(2.0, 1.0, item.size)))
```

The Second Fold:

```
item.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + myMethod(4.0, 3.0, item.size)))
```

The Third Fold:

```
item.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + myMethod(100.0, 10.0, item.size)))
```

where myMethod:

```
def myMethod(i: Double, j:Double, size: Integer) : Double = {
  (j - i) / size
  }
```

It is giving me an error which says that there are too many parameters for `foldLeft` as it requires 2 parameters.
`myMethod` returns a `Double`, and `_` is a `Double`. So, where is this extra parameter the compiler is seeing?

If I do this:

```
item.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _._1))
```

It sums up all the first `Double`s in each index of `item` - replacing _._1 with _._2 sums up all the second `Double`s in each index of `item`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `_` is equivalent to a new argument, so `(_ + myMethod(_._2, _._1, item.size))` is an anonymous function with 3 arguments: `(x, y, z) => x + myMethod(y._2, z._1, item.size)`.

What you want is `(acc, x) => acc + myMethod(x._2, x._1, item.size)`.

Comment: **Thank you**! I should've asked 4 hours ago. Coming from a Java background, I'm having a tough time grasping `_`. Thank you again!